# Down voted correct answer

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

The person who asked a question down voted my answer even though it was correct because he doesn't understand that it was correct despite his opinions. I lost the 2 points of reputation. I tried to ask for justification in the comments, and he just doesn't understand.

Do I have any recourse? Can I delete my answer to get me reputation points back?

I hate losing reputation due to pride and prejudice.

Comment: There isn't really anything you can do, but it doesn't really matter.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As votes are anonymous you can never be 100% certain who cast a vote even though it might seem obvious. In any case, is a couple of points worth thinking about? Deleting your answer will recover the points iirc (I could remember wrong though), but if your answer is indeed correct and beneficial to the community you might want to leave it as it is and take the two point hog for the greater good.

Comment: Looks like i will just accept the loss. I hate it on principle, but you are both right it's just not work it in the end

Comment: You are not going to last very long at SO if you take a downvote this personal.  SO users don't have to pass a driver license test before they can begin voting, fender benders happen.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  If it is a good, correct answer to a good question then others should vote it up.

Comment: I agree with Hans (+1). I do get downvoted once in a while on correct and accepted answers. The reason behind the decision may even be valid. Never take it personal. Turn it into an opportunity to improve. Life is a journey, and the community around StackOverflow is worth the downvote.

Comment: Absolutely, first few downvotes might hurt a bit, then you get used to it and ignore it. The community around SO is wonderful, and if you hang on, you will completely forget about this downvote in a few days :)

Comment: I never understood OP asking questions then downvoting the answers... unless they're completely stupid & harmful, that is. Answerer tries to help OP and is thanked by OP with a downvote...